# How can I instantiate a class that is associated with multiple tables and save it in multiple tables?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I am trying to model business processes. I have defined a class to keep the process blue prints (and two classes to keep activities and flows) and then I need to define the same number of tables to keep all of the data associated with the instances of that class.

I have a class called ProcessBluePrint. This class is practically defined by two classes called ActivityBluePrint and FlowBluePrint. So far everything works fine.

I need to define similar classes to hold data of the instances when created, namely Processes, Activities and Flows.

I tried to define the Process class to keep all of the instances of ProcessBluePrint, but I cannot get it right. In the django admin, when i try to add a new process (create an instance of ProcessBluePrint and save it in appropriate tables) Name and Description for the ProcessBluePrint is shown as a text while it should be a drop down. Perhaps the best way to do this is to make this a two step instantiating: step 1=select the ProcessBluePrint option and Step2=Select all the fields associated with that process model. I have attached snapshots to help you get what my problem is. I would really appreciate your help on this one. TIA

**Schematic**

[image]

**models.py**

```
class ProcessBluePrint(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,)
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=255,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ActivityBluePrint(models.Model):
    tag=models.CharField(max_length=10,)
    caption=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    process_blueprint=models.ForeignKey('ProcessBluePrint')
    activity=models.ForeignKey('Activity')
    action=models.ForeignKey('Action')
    actor=models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    def __str__(self):
        if self.caption:
            return self.process_blueprint.name + '_Activity_' + self.tag + ' (' + self.caption + ')'
        else:
            return self.process_blueprint.name + '_Activity_' + self.tag

    class Meta:
        ordering=['tag']


class FlowBluePrint(models.Model):
    caption=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    process_blueprint=models.ForeignKey('ProcessBluePrint')
    origin=models.ForeignKey('ActivityBluePrint',related_name='origin')
    destination=models.ForeignKey('ActivityBluePrint',related_name='destination')

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.process_blueprint.name + '_Flow_' + self.origin.tag  + 'to' + self.destination.tag

class Process(ProcessBluePrint, models.Model):
    type=models.ForeignKey('ProcessType')
    prodline=models.ForeignKey('ProdLine')
    business=models.ForeignKey('Business')
    project=models.ForeignKey('Project')
    start=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    end=models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=True)
    user_created=models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    date_created=models.DateTimeField()
    notes=models.TextField(max_length=500,)
    status=models.ForeignKey('Status')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Processes'
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create Activites and Flows whenever you create a process based on ProcessBlueprint?

Comment: @JeremyS. yes. Activities are tasks (shapes in a flowchart) and flows are the arrows. ProcessBluePrint would be a predefined process (flowchart) and every time we want to start a new process (instance) I want to create (instantiate) all of those activities and flows under that specific blueprint and store them in the database tables (it is where a new process starts)